# how to rollback on caught exception in Play framework?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework, transactions

I recently got into problem with play framework 2 @Transactional. Based on my tests, in the case of an exception, a transactional method would only rollback if the exception is unchecked (no catch block).
Here's my controller:

```
@Transactional
public Result myController(){
    ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
    try{
        JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();

        someFunction(json);      
        //doing some stuff using the json object inside someFunction
        //which I may intentionally throw an exception
        //based on some logic from within
        //(using "throw new RuntimeException()")

        result.put("success", true);
        return ok(Json.toJson(result));
    }catch(Exception e){
        result.put("success", false);
        result.put("msg", e.getMessage());
        return internalServerError(Json.toJson(result));
    }

}
```

I want my controller to always return a JSON in response. But this comes at the expense of not having a database rollback when I throw an exception in my code. I know that in spring you can add this to @Transactional annotation but I'm using play.db.jpa.Transactional. Is there any way I can do a rollback in my catch block without using spring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@Transactional` annotation basically wraps your action's code in a call to `DefaultJpaApi.withTransaction`. If you look at [the source](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.6.7/framework/src/play-java-jpa/src/main/java/play/db/jpa/DefaultJPAApi.java#L120-L161) you can see how this method handles the transaction.

Since you want to catch the exception, but still want to use the `withTransaction` behaviour, you could try removing the `@Transactional` annotation and calling `withTransaction` yourself within the action.

E.g.

```
class MyController {
  private final JPAApi jpa;
  @Inject
  public MyController(JPAApi jpa) {
    this.jpa = jpa;
  }

  public myAction() {
    ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
    try {
      JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();

      // Calls someFunction inside a transaction.
      // If there's an exception, rolls back transaction
      // and rethrows.
      jpa.withTransaction(() -> someFunction(json));

      // Transaction has been committed.
      result.put("success", true);
      return ok(Json.toJson(result));
    } catch(Exception e) {
      // Transaction has been rolled back.
      result.put("success", false);
      result.put("msg", e.getMessage());
      return internalServerError(Json.toJson(result));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've rewritten the answer with an alternative approach.

Comment: I did that and got compile error "unhandled exception: java.lang.throwable". How should I fix that? should I just replace Exception with Throwable in catch block?

Comment: Yes that would work, but what is throwing the `Throwable`?

Comment: withTransaction does

Comment: `withTransaction` just catches and rethrows exceptions, so it's probably not the root cause of the error. If you help to figure it out, you'll need to post more of the stack trace.

Comment: Oh, no the problem was easily fixable. withTransaction throws Throwable (not Exception) for whatever reason, but I was only catching the Exceptions (Exception extends Throwable). The other way around would've been fine because of Polymorphism. So long story short replacing "... catch (Exception e) ..." with "... catch(Throwable e) ..." would fix the issue.

Comment: Be careful with that code - catching `Throwable` can be dangerous because you can swallow important errors. I just [raised a Play issue](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/8023) because we should improve the JPA code.